# fork() has no homogeneous behaviour within shell

Tags: unix, fork, system

I've been testing this simple fork in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  int id = fork();
  pid_t p = getpid();
  pid_t pp = getppid();
  if (id != 0) {
    printf("I'm the parent, fork() gave me %i, my pid is %i and my parent's is %i \n",id,p,pp);
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("I'm the child, fork() gave me %i, my pid is %i and my parent's is %i \n",id,p,pp);
    return 0;
  }

}
```

I run it on Debian using VSCode and gcc.
Everytime I launch it, i get something like :

```
I'm the parent, fork() gave me 152911, my pid is 152906 and my parent's is 152890 
I'm the child, fork() gave me 0, my pid is 152911 and my parent's is 1 
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-bdyrp1e2.wm5" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-vixicyih.jop"
```

in the VSCode console. But when I invoke this script directly from the console, sometimes something "strange" happens :

```
me@laptop:~/Desktop/programmesC$ ./test_fork 
I'm the parent, fork() gave me 153571, my pid is 153570 and my parent's is 8738 

me@laptop:~/Desktop/programmesC$ I'm the child, fork() gave me 0, my pid is 153571 and my parent's is 1
```

Hence it behaves as if the parent gave the control back to the shell then the child executed. And in the meanwhile the shell has got the result of the children's print() ?

Which would mean that everytime I get a "proper" output (like in case #1), it's the child process who finishes its execution before its parent ? Am I correct or did I miss something ?

Comment: re: "the shell got the result of the children's print()"
The shell is running in a terminal.  The output of both the
parent and the child go to that terminal, but the shell never sees the
output from either the parent or the child.   Since the parent never
`waits`, the order in which the processes execute is non-deterministic and
the shell may print its prompt before or after the child writes its output.
But the shell will always write its prompt after the parent's output.

Comment: If the parent waits, would that mean that the execution order is deterministic? Or only that the print() order will be always the same in the shell (which in this case makes sense) ?

Comment: It depends.  If the parent `waits` and then prints, then the order is fully deterministic.  If the parent prints and then `waits`, the order in which the parent and the child print is not determined, but you get a guarantee that the both print before the shell prints its prompt.

Comment: How can I highlight the non deterministic behaviour ? Using the code displayed above, the parent always prints before the child. Same thing when I make it `wait` after `print` (even if they both print before the shell does)

Answer (score 0):

The order these three things are queued and ran will appear as if it’s random.

The code returns for both the parent and child. In your case, occasionally the parent ends and the shell is resumed before the child ends.